# How can I add two analysers to a field

Tags: elasticsearch

I use the nGram plugin for my queries but also I want to add the Phonetic Analysis to the same field on my mapping.

I'm trying the following settings, and it works well with the nGram plugin but I don't know how can I add the `dbl_metaphone` analyzer on my mapping.

```
curl -XPUT "127.0.0.1/index" -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "nGram_filter": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20,
               "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "punctuation",
                  "symbol"
               ]
            },
            "dbl_metaphone": { 
               "type":    "phonetic",
               "encoder": "double_metaphone"
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "nGram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "nGram_filter"
               ]
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            },
            "dbl_metaphone": {
               "tokenizer": "standard",
               "filter":    "dbl_metaphone"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "books": {
         "_all": {
            "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
         },
         "properties": {
            "descripcion":{
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
               "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
            },
            "categories":{
               "type": "nested",
               "properties": {
                  "nombre":{
                     "type": "string",
                     "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
                     "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this problem would be to have a [multi field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/_multi_fields.html) to analyze the data in different ways. Then to combine the results at query time you could use a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with either `should` or `must` clauses.

So the mapping would look something like this:

```
   "mappings": {
      "books": {
         "properties": {
            "descripcion": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
               "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
               "fields": {
                  "metaphone": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "analyzer": "dbl_metaphone"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

And a query would have to use the `descripcion` and `descripcion.metaphone` fields. The field `descripcion.metaphone` is the one analyzed with the `dbl_metaphone` analyzer.

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: yeah, this is exactly what i was looking for! thank you +1

Answer (score 0):

[Combo analyzer](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-analysis-combo/) is an option here. It allows you to specify multiple analyzers and it clubs the tokens from both the analyzers are the end result.

Comment: Are you sure about the analyzer? It has not been maintained for some time now. And it doesn't support elasticsearch 2.x